# Parse: [Error]: Error: Can't serialize an unsaved Parse.Object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm attempting to retrieve a book's author via cloud code, but I keep getting an error. Here's my code:

```
    //Retrieve Request Parameter
    bookId = request.params.bookId;

    //Create an empty Book Object
    var book = new Parse.Object("Book");
    book.id = bookId;

    //Define Book Relation
    var bookRelation = book.relation("authors");

    //Define Query
    var query = bookRelation.query();
    query.find ({
      success: function(books) {

        //Return Response
        response.success(books);
      },
      error: function(error) {

        //Return Response
        response.error(error);
      }
    });
```

The id is being passed correctly (checked this by logging to the console), but the error seems to be occurring at the following line: `var query = bookRelation.query();`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say because the Relation information on your object is not populated and obviously you cannot build a query to access its Relation data. You better load the object first and then attempt to access its Relation data:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Book");

query.get(request.params.bookId).then( function(book) {
    var bookRelation = book.relation("authors").query();
    return bookRelation.find();
}).then( function(authors) {
    response.success(authors);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```